# Roscd cannot find catkin_make 'd package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run ros kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. I try to use openpose ros wrapper on my platform. I share the error log below.
Best,

```
robolab3@robolab3-Inspiron-7566:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/robolab3/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _image_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Recognitions
...
[ 92%] Built target image_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target openpose_wrapper
[ 92%] Built target image_recognition_msgs_generate_messages
[ 94%] Building CXX object image_recognition/openpose_ros/CMakeFiles/openpose_wrapper.dir/src/openpose_wrapper_mock.cpp.o
[ 96%] Linking CXX shared library /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenpose_wrapper.so
[ 96%] Built target openpose_wrapper
Scanning dependencies of target openpose_ros_node
[ 98%] Building CXX object image_recognition/openpose_ros/CMakeFiles/openpose_ros_node.dir/src/openpose_ros_node.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/robolab3/catkin_ws/devel/lib/openpose_ros/openpose_ros_node
[100%] Built target openpose_ros_node
robolab3@robolab3-Inspiron-7566:~/catkin_ws$ roscd openpose_ros
roscd: No such package/stack 'openpose_ros'
robolab3@robolab3-Inspiron-7566:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch openpose_ros_node
[openpose_ros_node] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
robolab3@robolab3-Inspiron-7566:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286268/roscd-cannot-find-catkin_make-%27d-package/) by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
Please only include the console output that actually shows the error message in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> $ catkin_make
>     $ roscd openpose_ros
> ```

```
$ roslaunch openpose_ros_node
```

I don't see a `source devel/setup.bash` in your copy-pasted console text.

You need to "activate" your workspace after you've built it using `catkin_make`, otherwise utilities like `roscd` and `roslaunch` will not know where to find the new packages that you just built.

---

Edit: I only now see this:

> ```
> $ roslaunch openpose_ros_node
> ```

`roslaunch` takes either one or two arguments:

1. a direct path to a `.launch` file
2. a package name and a (package relative path to a) `.launch` file

Your invocation is neither: `openpose_ros_node` is not a package name (that would probably be `openpose_ros`), and it's also not a launch file name.

From the build output you show, it would appear `openpose_ros_node` is a ROS node (ie: an executable binary).

Those you should start with `rosrun $pkg $node_name`, not `roslaunch`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-03-25**:
Thank you for your answer. How can I activate it? I already exported it on .bashrc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-25**:\

> I already exported it on `.bashrc`

Doing it that way, your workspace is only `source`d (ie: activated) when you start a new bash session (ie: open a new terminal). Any pkgs that you add in such a session will not be found, untill you `catkin_make` and `source devel/setup.bash` yourself. Or ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-25**:
.. when you start a new terminal.

A simple rule is this: add or created a new package -> build your workspace and `source $CATKIN_WS/devel/setup.bash`.

If you don't, your new package(s) won't be found.

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-10**:
Hello, I had this issue previously and solved it with the way you showed. Today I changed the name of my node to make it easier to understand. I cleaned with catkin_make clean, rebuilt with catkin_make, and source devel/setup.bash . However now ros cannot locate my renamed node, nor it can build it.

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-10**:
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gesture_detector/gesture_listener.py]: gesture_detector

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/src

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share

:~/catkin_ws$ ls src/gesture_detector/scripts/

gesture_listener.py

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
Delete your `build` and `devel` folders, rebuild your workspace, then try again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
If this is a Python script, make sure that it has executable permissions set as well.

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-10**:
I solved it with going inside the catkin_ws/src/gesture_detector and executing catkin_create_package
I did not need to call chmod +x after this.